# UWP-XAML Items Control - How to apply dimensions of an item with the largest height/width to all items in an items control

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, itemscontrol

I'm using  to display items with descriptions.
Problem is, all items in the items control use the dimensions of the first item. I want to be able to use the dimensions of the largest item.

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:
[image]

Here's the code.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageContents.Items}" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlAligmentStyle}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="10">
                <StackPanel Width="300" Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleblockStyleText}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource DescriptionTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you host this?

Answer (score -1):

If you want, you could set a scrollviewer to allow scroll on the larger boxes. Have you set a dimension for the first object yet or is it the StackPanel that has the width and height set? In some cases the font may just be too big so you may have to downsize it or upsize the itemsControl. You can also choose scroll as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Edit: just found the solution. Set the height for the items control and stack panel. Not just the width. Set it to the desired height of the third item and everything should work